# Username and email not getting stored in mysql but password is, why

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a login and signup form for a site but i ran into an issue when signing up.
When the user signs up only the password is being stored in the database, the user name and email don't get stored in the database.

This is the server code:

```
        $sql = "INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $param_username, $param_password, $param_email);

        // Set parameters
        $param_username = $username;
        $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash
        $param_email = $email;

        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            // Redirect to login page
            header("location: home.php");
        } else{
            echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

And this is the sign up form:

```
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
        <label for="username">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" required value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
            <span ><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>


            <label for="text">
                <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
            </label>

            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email address" id="email" required  value="<?php echo $email; ?>">             



            <label for="password">
                <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
            </label>

            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" required  value="<?php echo $password; ?>">



            <label for="confirm_password">
                <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
            </label>
            <input type="password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="confirm password" id="password" required  value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">


            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        <p>Already have an account? <a href="index.php">Login here</a>.</p>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you bind param before set value for variables. With your code values of $param_username, $param_password, $param_emailis null when bind param. After, you set values for params.

```
// Set parameters
        $param_username = $username;
        $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash
        $param_email = $email;

//Bind Param
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $param_username, $param_password, $param_email);
```

Comment: Did you set value $_POST for $username, $password, $email?

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql)){

        !empty($username) or die("empty username");
        $param_username = $username;
        $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        !empty($email) or die("empty email");
        $param_email = $email;

        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $param_username, $param_password, $param_email);


        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            // Redirect to login page
            header("location: home.php");
        } else{
            echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

mysqli_close($con);
```